# how to show edit form on the "node/[nid]" page?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have a content type (budget), it is a custom content type

```
function budget_node_info() {
  return array(
    'budget' => array(
      'base' => 'budget',
      'name' => t('Budget'),
      'description' => t('Represents individual budget.'),
      'title_label' => t('Budget Name'),
      'locked' => TRUE
    )
  );
}
```

also I have the form function

```
function budget_form($node, $form_state) {
  drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.tabs');
  drupal_add_library('budget', 'highcharts');
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'budget') . '/js/budget_base.js');
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'budget') . '/js/' . $node->type . '.js');

  $form = node_content_form($node, $form_state);
  $config = variable_get($node->type);
```

I want to show the edit form on the node view page (I want to show form from node/[nid]/edit to node/[nid])?

I tried next:

```
function budget_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode){
  $node->content['edit-form'] = array(
    '#markup' => render(drupal_get_form('budget_form', $node)),
    '#weight' => 10,
  );
}
```

also I tried

```
function budget_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode){
  $node->content['edit-form'] = array(
  '#markup' => render(budget_form($node, array())),
    '#weight' => 10,
  );
}
```

2nd version show form but without any js or css loaded.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [function node_page_edit($node)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_page_edit/7) and seems like it works

```
function wp_budget_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode){
  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
  $node->content['edit-form'] = array(
    '#markup' => render(node_page_edit($node)),
    '#weight' => 10,
  );
}
```

also for new (empty) form you should use node_add function [function node_add($type](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_add/7)